# Ember build error

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, routes

When running `ember build --environment=production` everything seems to compile just fine. Putting the files inside `dist/` on my server goes fine as well, but when I click a link on my page I get the following error:

```
      vendor-ef159bc….js:11 Error while processing route: account Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at Object.parse (native)
at ae.parseJSON (http://localhost:8000/assets/vendor-ef159bc608efff575c24c5e13c2d1218.js:3:12644)
at W (http://localhost:8000/assets/vendor-ef159bc608efff575c24c5e13c2d1218.js:1:15665)
at n (http://localhost:8000/assets/vendor-ef159bc608efff575c24c5e13c2d1218.js:3:13996)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/assets/vendor-ef159bc608efff575c24c5e13c2d1218.js:3:20168)`.
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a non working project?

Comment: Usually when expecting JSON and instead seeing `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`, this indicates that you are retrieving HTML instead of JSON.  When you get this error, I would use a REST client to retrieve that URL and this should give you a clue about why this is happening.

Comment: Wells its the `vendor.js` file. So Its probably js. But I mean a git repo where this problem is reproducible.

Comment: Well, the weird part is that it works in dev mode, just not when building it for production

Comment: True. Doesn't work in production mode. Facing the same issue. Any resolution ?

Comment: Sorry, haven't tried anything since. I started a new project and some bugs were fixed, maybe you could try updating ember :D

Answer (score 0):

I've solved similar problem recently by downgrading from jQuery 2 to jQuery 1 in bower.json, then deleting jQuery folder in bower_components, then running `bower install` command.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this ?

Comment: @PiyushChoudhary I didn't touch Ember since, have you?